# Trasformation from ECEF to ENU

Tags: coordinates, coordinate-system

I am trying to transform a local vector r<sub>ECEF</sub> from ECEF coordinate system to ENU coordinate system (r<sub>ENU</sub>) where

ECEF = earth-centered earth-fixed coordinate system

ENU = East, North, Up coordinates, a local Earth based coordinate system

I saw in more then one book the following equation:

[image: r_enu]

where

[image: R_L],

[image: r_3_theta]

and

[image: R_2_theta]

What i don't understand is why

[image: R_3_pi]

since [image: cos_pi] and [image: sin_pi]

What am i missing?

Comment: (1) This site does not support TeX markup.  You can usually get by with code markup (indent lines by four spaces). (2) What is "retaliative distance"?

Comment: @whuber, thanks for your comment, fixed (relative distance).

Comment: For your formulas to be readable, you will need to remove all the TeX markup.

Comment: @whuber, i hope it is now understandable

Comment: Your formulas appear to be asking about [Euler angles](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerAngles.html) but the connection to your question is not evident.

Comment: @whuber, yes you are right, the matrices are part of Euler's rotation theorem. In this case they are used to rotate the vector r_{ECEF} which is placed on the earth surface into r_{ENU}.

Comment: Did you see how my link to the MathWorld article on Euler angles answers your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to check that this is right is to multiply out the
matrices to get

```
     [     -sin(lambda)            cos(lambda)          0     ]
R =  [ -sin(phi)*cos(lambda)  -sin(phi)*sin(lambda)  cos(phi) ]
     [  cos(phi)*cos(lambda)   cos(phi)*sin(lambda)  sin(phi) ]
```

The three rows are the unit vectors E, N, and U in ECEF coordinates; so
when you form R.r_ecef you are computing the components of r_enu by
resolving r_ecef into its ENU coordinates.

Incidently, you are missing the translation component in this
conversion.  The origin of the ENU system is normally on the surface of
the ellipsoid while the origin of ECEF is the center of the earth.

See, for example, **Other Earth-based coordinate systems** and **Conversion calculations** at [**Geodetic datum**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_datum).

Comment: thanks for you answer. I computed the result of R_L and saw that it is correct. My question was refering to R_3(\pi)... why R_3(\pi) is not equal to diag(-1,-1,1), since cos(pi) = -1 and sin(pi) = 0.

Comment: So clearly the R_3(pi) is wrong!  Presumably, it's supposed to be R_3(-pi/2).  But don't ask me why, because I don't find it particularly useful to decompose R into individual rotations in this case.  I prefer just to go straight to R by listing the components of E, N, and U.

Comment: ok, so i will try to compute it and see if i get -pi/2. Strange since i saw pi in more then one book....